# React role based authentication if the two users are from two different tables

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I'm new to React/Node and working on a learning project. It's a platform that connects users (freelancers) with nonprofit companies. I would like users to sign up and login as A) user or B) company. I can't figure out how to do this, and all the guides I found are for when your users are all coming from the same table, but with different auth levels (eg. user, admin, etc..).

In my case, it's different. `users` and `companies` are two different resources. A user can view `/companies` and click a button to connect to that company. A user can view a page that lists all their connections. Likewise, a `company` can login and view a page that lists all the users that connected with them.

Right now, the backend is working successfully. Both users/companies can signup/login, and you get a token back as expected (tested in Insomnia). I'm using JSON Web Tokens.

On the frontend, users can signup, login, make connections, and view their connections successfully. Now I just want companies to do the same, but have no idea how. I made an attempt at doing it, but when a company tries to login, they're directed to the homepage and they're not logged in. No error messages show up.

Not sure what code to post, but I will keep this concise. This is all the relevant code (shortened). I would appreciate any help, or pointers.

**schema**

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
  company_handle VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL,
  company_name TEXT NOT NULL  
  role TEXT DEFAULT 'company'
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
  password TEXT NOT NULL,  
  role TEXT DEFAULT 'user'
);

CREATE TABLE connections (
  username VARCHAR(25)
    REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
  company_handle VARCHAR(25)
    REFERENCES companies ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY (username, company_handle)
);
```

**Frontend**

**App.js**

```
function App() {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [currentCompany, setCurrentCompany] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useLocalStorage(TOKEN_LOCAL_STORAGE_ID);
  const [connectionHandles, setConnectionHandles] = useState([]);

  // Load user info from the API 
  useEffect(function loadUserInfo() {
    async function getCurrentUser() {
      if (token) {
        try {
          let { username } = jwt.decode(token);
          let { companyHandle } = jwt.decode(token);
          VolunteerApi.token = token;

          if (username) {
            let currentUser = await VolunteerApi.getCurrentUser(username);
            setCurrentUser(currentUser);
          }

          if (companyHandle) {
            let currentCompany = await VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(companyHandle);
            setCurrentCompany(currentCompany);
          }

        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Problem with the loadUserInfo function", err);
          setCurrentUser(null);
          setCurrentCompany(null);
        }
      }      
    }
    
    getCurrentUser();
  }, [token]);  
  

  // Login user function 
  async function loginUser(loginData) {
    try {
      let token = await VolunteerApi.loginUser(loginData);
      setToken(token);
      return {
        success: true
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Problem with the login function", err);
      return {
        success: false, err
      };
    }
  }

  // Login company function 
  async function loginCompany(loginData) {
    try {
      let token = await VolunteerApi.loginCompany(loginData);
      setToken(token);
      return {
        success: true
      };
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Problem with the login function", err);
      return {
        success: false, err
      };
    }
  }    

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ connectionHandles, setConnectionHandles, currentUser, setCurrentUser, currentCompany, setCurrentCompany }}>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Routes loginUser={loginUser} loginCompany={loginCompany} />
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**api.js**

```
class VolunteerApi {  
  static token;

  static async request(endpoint, data = {}, method = "get") {
    console.debug("API Call:", endpoint, data, method);

    const url = `${BASE_URL}/${endpoint}`;
    const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${VolunteerApi.token}` };
    const params = (method === "get")
      ? data
      : {};

    try {
      return (await axios({ url, method, data, params, headers })).data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("API Error:", err.response);
      let message = err.response.data.error.message;
      throw Array.isArray(message) ? message : [message];
    }
  }  

  // Login company
  static async loginCompany(data) {
    let res = await this.request(`auth/login-company`, data, "post");
    return res.token;
  }

  // Login user
  static async loginUser(data) {
    let res = await this.request(`auth/login-user`, data, "post");
    return res.token;
  }
}
```

**Backend**

**auth.js**

```
router.post("/login-company", async function (req, res, next) {
      try {    
        const { companyHandle, password } = req.body;
        const company = await Company.authenticate(companyHandle, password);
        const token = createToken(company);
        return res.json({ token });
      } catch (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
    });
    
router.post("/login-user", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {  
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.authenticate(username, password);
    const token = createToken(user);
    return res.json({ token });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

**token.js**

```
function createToken(user) {
  console.assert(undefined,
      "createToken passed user with an undefined user");

  let payload = {
    username: user.username,
    companyHandle: user.companyHandle
  };

  return jwt.sign(payload, SECRET_KEY);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you wish to achieve is that your same app can be viewed with 2 different perspectives (User view or Company view) using who logged in as your flag to show the correct data. Having different roles for the same page can be tricky but thankfully there are a number of ways to achieve this.

What I recommend as the simplest approach would be conditional rendering.

When someone logs in as a user or a company you can save that detail to the browsers local storage using `localStorage.setItem("UserType", "Example");`  and you can get this information using `localStorage.getItem("UserType");`

Then when the user or company is in your page using that detail you can render the right elements like so:

`{condition == true && (<> <Module/> </>)}`

Now since we are using react we can import whole js files as modules. so you can have something that looks like this:

```
import UserPage from 'somewhere/User.js' 
import CompanyPage from 'somewhere/Company.js' 

function MainApp() {
const userOrCompany = localStorage.getItem("UserType")
return(
<>
 {userOrCompany === 'User' && (<> <UserPage/> </>)}
 {userOrCompany === 'Company' && (<> <CompanyPage/> </>)}
 </>
);
}

export default MainApp;
```

Also, I recommend handling tokens from the backend for security reasons. That way you can condition your backend data to needing a token before returning anything :D